# Abaqus/Python assign material from csv to volume fraction

Tags: python, csv, abaqus

Im using the following code to create partitions

```
path = "C:\Users\s.espinosa14\OneDrive - Universidad de los Andes\Documents\Civil\Tesis Silvia\Cubos\cc.txt"
datalist = []
with open(path, "rb") as fp:
    for row in fp.readlines():
        tmp = row.split(",")
        try:
            datalist.append((float(tmp[0]), float(tmp[1]), float(tmp[2])))
        except:pass

numcor = len(datalist)
for i in range(0,numcor):
    p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1']
    p.DatumPointByCoordinate(coords=datalist[i])

for ii in range(2,numcor,3):
    p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1']
    print(ii)
    c = p.cells
    pickedCells = c
    v1, e1, d2 = p.vertices, p.edges, p.datums
    p.PartitionCellByPlaneThreePoints(cells=pickedCells, 
        point1=d2[ii],
    point2=d2[ii+1],
    point3=d2[ii+2])
```

Now im trying to assign a material to each partition using. I have the coordinates and the material type in a csv

```
datalist2 = []
with open(path2, "rb") as fp2:
    for row in fp2.readlines():
        tmp = row.split(",")
        try:
            datalist2.append((float(tmp[0]), float(tmp[1]), float(tmp[2]),float(tmp[3])))
        except:pass

numcor = len(datalist)
for i in range(0,numcor):
    p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1']
    c = p.cells
    pickedcell = c.findAt(tmp[0],tmp[1],tmp[2])
    p.HomogeneousSolidSection(material=
'tmp[3]', name='name', thickness=None)
```

The csv has the x,y,z and the material (1 or 0), 1 is one material and 0 is another material.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, add some code and avoid to use external links to images. This will help your question to be answered faster.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes Just did the adjustments, thanks for your suggestions.